# DataTable: Get the value of the first cell from a selected row

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

I'm trying to delete a selected row from a DataTable by retrieving the value of the first cell (id) and passing it to the deleteRow function. How do I get this value?

```
                         child: DataTable(
                              columns: data.first.keys
                                  .map((dynamic keys) => DataColumn(label: Text(keys.toString())))
                                  .toList(),
                              rows: data.map((map) {
                                return DataRow(
                                    onSelectChanged: (bool selected) {
                                      if (selected) {
                                        try {
                                          //determine the id of the selected row
                                          int selectedId = /*get index of selected row and return value of the first cell*/
                                          //delete row associated with id in db
                                          deleteRow(selectedId);
                                          //update ui to remove that row
                                          setState(() {});
                                        } catch (e) {
                                          return SnackBar(
                                            content: Text('Cant delete this row. EXCEPTION: $e'),
                                          );
                                        }
                                      }
                                    },
                                    cells: map.values.map((dynamic val) => DataCell(Text(val.toString()))).toList());
                              }).toList()),
```

Comment: do you have any id(unique way to identify) according to your items ?

Comment: Yes, each item has a unique id. it is stored in the first cell of each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Map> data = [], selected = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    data.add({'id': 'Emp1', 'name': 'Naveen', 'salary': 50000});
    data.add({'id': 'Emp3', 'name': 'Satish', 'salary': 35000});
    data.add({'id': 'Emp2', 'name': 'Ram', 'salary': 40000});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
              selected.length < 1
                  ? 'Nothing Selected !'
                  : 'First cell : ${selected[0].values.toList()[0]}',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          DataTable(
              columns: data.first.keys
                  .map((dynamic keys) =>
                      DataColumn(label: Text(keys.toString())))
                  .toList(),
              rows: data.map((map) {
                return DataRow(
                    selected: selected.contains(map),
                    onSelectChanged: (boo) {
                      if (boo) {
                        setState(() {
                          selected.add(map);
                        });
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          selected.remove(map);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    cells: map.values.map((value) {
                      return DataCell(Text(value.toString()));
                    }).toList());
              }).toList()),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

[image: pic]

Comment: how does selected = [] get populated with data?

Comment: As my answer says, selected is empty by default then when you select row it adds a map into selected list. We get by calling selected [0]. If you want to select only one item/row clear selected list before adding selected row

Comment: selected[0].values.toList()[0] only returns the first cell of the first map. How do you return the first cell of every map in a list?

Comment: Your question is to get only first cell of selected ROW not selected ROWS ! If you selected all rows you can get the by iterating through the selected list !

Comment: Nvmnd I got it. I used forEach to gather them in a list