# Flutter DataTable -Tap on entire Row

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

im new to Flutter. I need help on OnTap in DataCell. For example, instead of tapping one cell, I want the Row.

Heres my codes

```
DataTable(
     columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("Title"),
          ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("Contacts"),
          ),
         )
        ],
         rows: contracts.map((contract) => DataRow(
             cells: [
               DataCell(Text(contract.title),
                  onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => List(),),
                           );
                         }),
               DataCell(Text(contract.contacts),
                  onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => List(),),
                           );
                         }),).toList()
```

i want to click on a specific row and it will route to another page also sends the index value of it.

Comment: This may help you ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/59783496/5557479

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue, realised you could use the `onSelectChanged` from the `DataRow`.

Example from the `DataTable`

```
rows: searchList.map((item) {
        return DataRow(
          onSelectChanged: (bool value) {
             // ENTER CALLBACK HERE (It's not restricted to use the bool)
          },
          cells: ...
```

Note, this will make the `Checkbox` visible, if you do not require this then make sure you force the `showCheckboxColumn` to `false` in the `DataTable`:

```
    return DataTable(
      showCheckboxColumn: false,
      columns: [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

To **make the entire widget tappable**

just wrap your widget with
`InkWell()` or `GestureDetector` Widget

`InkWell()` widget will add a clickable shadow kind of effect when you press on the widget

whereas `GestureDetector()` widget won't

In your case instead of wrapping `DataCell` just wrap your `DataRow` widget

Comment: This doesn't work since the property `rows` of `DataTable` expects a `List<DataRow>` so you can't assign a `List<GestureDetector>` to it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a property in DataRow you can implement called **onSelectChanged** where you can put your function inside.

```
bool isSelected = false;

DataRow(
 selected: isSelected,
 onSelectChanged: (x) {
  setState(() {
   isSelected = x;
  });
 },
 cells: <DataCell>[
  DataCell(
   Text('Row1'),
  ),
 ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks, but what im trying to do is routing it to another page and sending the index value of that row.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DataRow.byIndex(), then use that index when wrapping your DataRow in a GestureDetector.

Comment: What I ended up doing was just have the same callback for every cell in the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataTable(
        dividerThickness: 1,
        headingRowColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.grey[200]),
        headingTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        showBottomBorder: true,
        showCheckboxColumn: false,
        columns: [
          DataColumn(label: Text('序号')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('错误类型')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('错误简介')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('最近上报时间')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('影响设备数')),
        ],
        rows: [
          DataRow(onSelectChanged: (isSelected) {

          }, cells: [
            DataCell(Text('1')),
            DataCell(Text('1001')),
            DataCell(Text('123')),
            DataCell(Text('10%')),
            DataCell(Text('123123')),
          ])
        ],
      )
```

Comment: showCheckboxColumn: false,

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**